# Javascript performance and comparing objects vs properties of the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

In javascript is it faster to compare via a property or the entire object that has tons of properties? Below is what I currently have but my object has a ton of properties, and the objects list is quite large.  Is it better to create a list from a single property off say `id` and compare the `id` of the object? `objectids.indexOf(object1.id)`.  Would I see a performance increase?

**Comparing Against The Object**

```
objects.indexOf(object1);

function Object() {
  this.id = 1;
  this.name = "test";
}
```

Comment: How do you plan on comparing the entire object? In any case, comparing a unique identifier would be the way to go.

Comment: comparing numbers is faster than comparing objects.

Comment: `indexOf` will compare object references, so you'd need to show how you're populating `objects` to know if it would even work...

Comment: https://jsperf.com/ make tests and find out

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qx6wgem0/5/ - Admittedly this may not be entirely correct, however from running the tests 10000 times on a dataset of 20000 simple objects, it looks like doing an `indexOf` by object reference is roughly twice as fast as doing an `indexOf` by ID.

Comment: @NagaSaiA `.filter()` iterates every item, every time, whereas `indexOf()` will stop once it finds the item, therefore I don't see any instance where `.filter()` would be quicker than `indexOf()`.  However I did test `some()`, which behaves similarly to `indexOf()`, and it was nearly 20x slower: https://jsfiddle.net/qx6wgem0/6/

Comment: However, it's important to note that my tests above didn't factor actually *creating* the array of integers, but rather operating on an existing set. If we include the step to create the list of IDs, it performs about 20x worse than object reference lookup, similar to `.some()`: https://jsfiddle.net/qx6wgem0/6/

Comment: So what you are telling me is reference is still better then what the alternative is?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/baey2t4d/6/ another test. It seems like in Chrome, comparing objects is faster while in Firefox it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Note that both versions aren't equivalent:

```
  ({ id: 1}) === ({ id: 1 }) // false      
  ({ id: 1}).id === ({ id: 1 }).id // true
```

If both cases work the same `indexOf` has to traverse half the array on average to get the index, it doesn't really matter if that array is an array of ids or objects. To get `O(1)` lookup time use a `Set` instead.